# Iterate through a dictionary inside a for loop

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, nested

I'm trying to print the values of a dictionary inside a for loop, currently this is what I'm getting:

```
    Site 1
    {'Port': '1/0/2', 'Link-Status': 'Up', 'Vlans': '81,1001,1101,1301,1303'}
    {'Port': '1/0/4', 'Link-Status': 'Down', 'Vlans': '1007'}
    {'Port': '1/0/11', 'Link-Status': 'Up', 'Vlans': '30,31,81,82'}
    {'Port': '1/0/13', 'Link-Status': 'Up', 'Vlans': '30,31,81,82,1001,1101'}
    {'Port': '1/0/14', 'Link-Status': 'Up', 'Vlans': '1007'}
    Site 1
    {'Port': '1/0/2', 'Link-Status': 'Up', 'Vlans': '82,1301,2001,2101'}
    {'Port': '1/0/4', 'Link-Status': 'Down', 'Vlans': '2007'}
    {'Port': '1/0/11', 'Link-Status': 'Up', 'Vlans': '30,31,81,82'}
    {'Port': '1/0/13', 'Link-Status': 'Up', 'Vlans': '30,31,81,82,1301,2001,2101'}
    {'Port': '1/0/14', 'Link-Status': 'Up', 'Vlans': '2007'}
    Site 1
    {'Port': '1/0/2', 'Link-Status': 'Up', 'Vlans': '1006,1102'}
    {'Port': '1/0/4', 'Link-Status': 'Down', 'Vlans': '1007'}
    {'Port': '1/0/11', 'Link-Status': 'Up', 'Vlans': '20,21'}
    {'Port': '1/0/13', 'Link-Status': 'Up', 'Vlans': '20,21,1006,1102'}
    {'Port': '1/0/14', 'Link-Status': 'Up', 'Vlans': '1007'}
    Site 1
    {'Port': '1/0/2', 'Link-Status': 'Down', 'Vlans': '2006,2102'}
    {'Port': '1/0/4', 'Link-Status': 'Down', 'Vlans': '2007'}
    {'Port': '1/0/11', 'Link-Status': 'Up', 'Vlans': '20,21'}
    {'Port': '1/0/13', 'Link-Status': 'Up', 'Vlans': '20,21,2006,2102'}
    {'Port': '1/0/14', 'Link-Status': 'Up', 'Vlans': '2007'}
```

I have tried indexing the values inside the for loop, but I haven't had luck with this:

```
    def main():
        input_site = new_site.keys()
        print(new_site.values())
        for element in input_site:
            i=0
            print(list(new_site.values())[i])
            i+=1
            processInput(element,type)
```

This is the content of my dictionary:

```
    print(new_site.values())
    dict_values(['Site 1', 'Site 3', 'Site 7', 'Site 9'])
```

This is what I'm aiming for:

```
    Site 1
    {'Port': '1/0/2', 'Link-Status': 'Up', 'Vlans': '81,1001,1101,1301,1303'}
    {'Port': '1/0/4', 'Link-Status': 'Down', 'Vlans': '1007'}
    {'Port': '1/0/11', 'Link-Status': 'Up', 'Vlans': '30,31,81,82'}
    {'Port': '1/0/13', 'Link-Status': 'Up', 'Vlans': '30,31,81,82,1001,1101'}
    {'Port': '1/0/14', 'Link-Status': 'Up', 'Vlans': '1007'}
    Site 3
    {'Port': '1/0/2', 'Link-Status': 'Up', 'Vlans': '82,1301,2001,2101'}
    {'Port': '1/0/4', 'Link-Status': 'Down', 'Vlans': '2007'}
    {'Port': '1/0/11', 'Link-Status': 'Up', 'Vlans': '30,31,81,82'}
    {'Port': '1/0/13', 'Link-Status': 'Up', 'Vlans': '30,31,81,82,1301,2001,2101'}
    {'Port': '1/0/14', 'Link-Status': 'Up', 'Vlans': '2007'}
    Site 7
    {'Port': '1/0/2', 'Link-Status': 'Up', 'Vlans': '1006,1102'}
    {'Port': '1/0/4', 'Link-Status': 'Down', 'Vlans': '1007'}
    {'Port': '1/0/11', 'Link-Status': 'Up', 'Vlans': '20,21'}
    {'Port': '1/0/13', 'Link-Status': 'Up', 'Vlans': '20,21,1006,1102'}
    {'Port': '1/0/14', 'Link-Status': 'Up', 'Vlans': '1007'}
    Site 9
    {'Port': '1/0/2', 'Link-Status': 'Down', 'Vlans': '2006,2102'}
    {'Port': '1/0/4', 'Link-Status': 'Down', 'Vlans': '2007'}
    {'Port': '1/0/11', 'Link-Status': 'Up', 'Vlans': '20,21'}
    {'Port': '1/0/13', 'Link-Status': 'Up', 'Vlans': '20,21,2006,2102'}
    {'Port': '1/0/14', 'Link-Status': 'Up', 'Vlans': '2007'}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your `for-loop` you have the following lines

```
for element in input_site:
    i=0 # <---
    print(list(new_site.values())[i])
    i+=1
```

At each iteration you assign i to be 0, then print the i-th element of `list(new_site.values())` and then increase its value by one.
The same will happen for the next iterations.
So, to fix it, `i` should be moved outside the loop.

Comment: Thanks, I put the i=0 before the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the `i=0` problem, there are some major issues with your for-loop:

```
for element in input_site:
    print(list(new_site.values())[i])
    i+=1
    processInput(element,type)
```

- Every time you iterate, you copy the ENTIRE list of values, just to access a single element.
- `element` is a key in the `new_site` dict. There are ways to ask for the value associated with a key. Go over [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) and [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) for `dict`.
- When iterating over a dict, if you want both keys and values, you should use [`.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items), not [`.keys()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys). Sample code:

  ```
  for key, value in d.items():
      ...
  ```
- When you pass `type` to `processInput`, you are passing the function named `type`. `type` is a function that takes in an object and tells you what type it has. However, when you pass `type`, you are just passing the function itself. Is that really what you want? You need to *call* the function on an object to get its type.

I recommend reviewing the material, or finding a tutor to explain to you what each part of your code does. Prepare some questions beforehand.